# Unable to get desired output from python list

Tags: python

I have a little issue with my the following python code I have.
I have a list which contains the following elements. This list could also be empty with NO contents.

As you can see, the `This is my first stock I bought 01.27.2019` is encode and I have to decode it to remove the `b''`. When I perform the split operation on the mylist, I get `''` as the first item in the list, and I am not sure why.

```
mylist = "$17$b'This is my first stock I bought 01.27.2019'"
The fields in mylist are seperated by a $ rather than a ,
```

```
        tmp_list = mylist.split('$')
        print (tmp_list) # ['', '17', "b'This is my first stock I bought 01.27.2019'"] ---> Not sure why I have the '' as the first item in the tmp_list
        tmp_iter = iter(tmp_list)
        res['myinfo']= '{' + '},{'.join(f'{n},{s}' for n, s in zip(tmp_iter, tmp_iter)) + '}'
```

I want my `res['myinfo']` to be `"{{17, This is my first stock I bought 01.27.2019}, ...many more {,}}`.

At times, the `res['myinfo']` could just be "{}" if the `mylist = [""]`.

I am not sure on how to fix my code, any help would be appreciated.

Comment: `mylist = [$17$b'This is my first stock I bought 01.27.2019']` That's not valid Python code.  What are those dollar signs doing?

Comment: Those are the contents of my list. Not sure what you mean its invalid code? The fields in my list are seperated by a ```$``` rather than a ```,```.

Comment: It causes a `SyntaxError`. My guess is you actually  have something like `mylist = "$17$b'This is my first stock I bought 01.27.2019'"`

Comment: @RobBricheno Exactly!! Made update to the question

Comment: "_When I perform the split operation on the mylist, I get '' as the first item in the list_" That's probably because the first character in the string is your separator (`$`). What comes before that? Nothing.

Comment: You can also try to do something like this: tmp_list = mylist[1:].split('$')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all

```
mylist = "$17$b'This is my first stock I bought 01.27.2019'"
```

Should be

```
mylist = "17$b'This is my first stock I bought 01.27.2019'"
```

Just as @takendarkk said

> That's probably because the first character in the string is your
>   separator ($). What comes before that? Nothing. – takendarkk

As for decoding your string assuming they are all like: " ***b'*** *some string* ***'*** " and have an age before them you have to decode every odd indexed elements in your list. A very straigth forward solution could be:

```
def decodeString(stringToDecode):
    decodedList = []
    for i in range(2, len(stringToDecode)-1):  #every character except the first 2 and the last one
        decodedList.append(stringToDecode[i])
    decodedString = ''.join(decodedList)
    return decodedString

for i in range(len(tmp_list)):
    if i % 2 == 1:                                 #every odd indexed element
        decodedString = decodeString(tmp_list[i])
        tmp_list[i] = decodedString
```

And also it seems like you need 1 more layer of '{}' here:

```
res['myinfo']= '{' + '},{'.join(f'{n},{s}' for n, s in zip(tmp_iter, tmp_iter)) + '}'
```

This way your `res['myinfo']` is `{17,This is my first stock I bought 01.27.2019},{18,This is my second stock I bought 01.28.2019}` but if you want it to be `'{{17,This is my first stock I bought 01.27.2019},{18,This is my second stock I bought 01.27.2019}}'` as you said you need:

```
res['myinfo']= '{' + '{' + '},{'.join(f'{n},{s}' for n, s in zip(tmp_iter, tmp_iter)) + '}' + '}'
```